# How can I set the default 'table border style' in LyX layout?

Tags: tables, lyx, lyx-layouts

I want to specify the style of table borders (*formal* vs. *default*) in a LyX `.layout` file. How can I do that?

Comment: Track progress here: [How can I set the default 'table border style' in LyX layout?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/76779) and [LyX Ticket request 8360](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8360).

Comment: Currently, this is not possible. I opened a Feature Request at LyX at  http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8360

Answer (score 4):

This is at the moment not possible, but a feature request has been posted at LyX.org:

- http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8360

Comment: yes, I know, I filed it ;-)

Comment: @andreas-h Of course, I know. I posted this answer during our [last "Answer the unanswered" session in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7538881#7538881) (meta post [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1560/586)). That's why I made it community wiki, which means I won't get any reputation for it (I basically copied you comment anyway ...). I should perhaps have posted a comment asking you to post an answer instead, sorry about that.